# how to tune up spark Jobs on a cluster with different amount of memory and cores

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I'm working on a spark project and i'm using a hadoop cluster of 3 nodes with the following configuration:

- **8cores and 16go of Ram** (Namenode, Application Master, nodemanager and spark master and worker).
- **4cores and 8go of Ram** (datanode, nodemanager and worker)
- **4cores and 4go of Ram** (datanode, nodemanager and worker)
  so i'm using the following configuration :

  `pyspark --master yarn-client --driver-memory 3g --executor-memory 1g --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 1`

What's the best amount of executor, memory and cores tu use All my cluster performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This essentially boils down to how much you need to process the data. If you have the whole cluster to process data you can use completely.

`pyspark --master yarn-client --driver-memory 3g --executor-memory 1g --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 1`

Here you aren't using the complete cluster. You are using 3gb driver and 1 gb executors with 3 executors meaning total 3gb of memory whereas you have 12 Gb memory in the cluster and 8 cores. One alternate configuration you could try

`pyspark --master yarn-client --driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 3g --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 3`

This uses the complete cluster.

However, the executor-memory configuration is mostly based on the job requirement. You need to tune that with multiple try. You can check this [document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html) for tuning.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) blog post by Sandy Ryza nicely explains allocation of resources with various overheads, and [here](http://c2fo.io/c2fo/spark/aws/emr/2016/07/06/apache-spark-config-cheatsheet/) is a handy Excel cheat-sheet.

However if you're new to Spark and/or frequently change cluster size/type, might I suggest enabling [dynamic allocation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation)?

Comment: Thnx appriciated